# How to increase space between label and chart area?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, chart.js2

All my labels are on the top of the bars. I can see this:

[image]

but I want that would be like this:
[image]

Padding doesn't work for xAxes but works for yAxes.

```
    legend: {display: false},
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        position: 'top',
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 1,
          min: 0,
          autoSkip: false,
          fontColor: '#3f7ba2',
          fontStyle: 600,
          fontFamily: 'Italic',
        },
        gridLines: {
          color: '#dedfe7',
          tickMarkLength: 0,
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          fontColor: '#62aae8',
          padding: 5
        },
        gridLines: {
          color: '#dedfe7' //b5cce2
        }
      }],
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue that only persists in chart.js version 2.6.0 and lower. As you can read in the [release notes](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.7.0) under the bug fixes it says that in PR 4403 `ticks.padding` option now applies to vertical and horizontal scales.

So to solve your issue you will need to update to a version of chart.js higher or equal to 2.7.0

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        position: 'top',
        ticks: {
          padding: 100
        }
      }],
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```