# How can I add in-between spaces in ChartJS labels?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am trying to create the spacing in between the labels of ['70%', '25%', '5%']. When I use padding I'm getting space around the labels. Is there another way to create this?

[image: my chart with three labels]

Here is my code:

```
const data = {
            labels: ['70%', '25%', '5%'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'My First Dataset',
                    data: [300, 50],
                    backgroundColor: ['#3ECE80', '#DFDFDF'],
                    hoverOffset: 4,
                },
                { weight: 0.9 },
                {
                    label: 'My Second Dataset',
                    data: [432, 42],
                    backgroundColor: ['#B3B3B3', '#DFDFDF'],
                    hoverOffset: 4,
                },
                { weight: 0.9 },
                {
                    label: 'My Third Dataset',
                    data: [23, 124],
                    backgroundColor: ['#DFDFDF', '#FF6384'],
                    hoverOffset: 4,
                },
            ],
        };


        const options = {
        // maintainAspectRatio: true,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                position: 'left',
                labels: {
                    // textAlign: 'right',
                    pointStyle: 'circle',
                    usePointStyle: true,
                    padding: 20,
                },
            },
        },
        layout: {
            padding: {
                // right: 100,
            },
        },
    };
```

React ChartJs 2 v^5.2.0

ChartJs v^4.3.0

Comment: Related: [How to remove space between labels in chartjs doughnut in reactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76277715) and [How to increase space between label and chart area in chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70879016/).